# Installation is incomplete.%0 error log help (2.2.2)

Tags: error, installation, log, name, magento2.2.2

Step 6: Install

```
                                                            Installing... 0%
```

**Installation is incomplete. 
Check the console log for errors before trying again.**

```
 [ERROR] InvalidArgumentException: Constant name is expected. in /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php:23
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant->evaluate(Array)
    #1 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
    #2 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
    #3 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php(102): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
    #4 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(171): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom->convert(Object(DOMDocument))
    #5 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(130): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
    #6 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(76): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('global')
    #7 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global')
    #8 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(187): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array)
    #9 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ObjectManagerProvider.php(62): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array)
    #10 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigOptionsListCollector.php(91): Magento\Setup\Model\ObjectManagerProvider->get()
    #11 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigModel.php(95): Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsListCollector->collectOptionsLists()
    #12 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(511): Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigModel->process(Array)
    #13 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDeploymentConfig(Array)
    #14 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #15 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
    #16 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
    #17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #18 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #19 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #20 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #21 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #22 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #23 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #24 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #25 /home/yoreselp/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #26 /home/yoreselp/public_html/setup/index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
```

Comment: and again /setup screen "Constant name is expected." step 1 just 
I am uploading setup and app 
the folder.

Comment: Is this regular instance of Magento? Without any additional modules?

Comment: have you tried changing max_execution_time as specified here? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142895)